# How to pass variables without giving people the chance to see their value

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm programming a quiz and I've got a (hopefully) small problem:

I get the questions and their answers from a database and then I display it using a html form. By clicking on an answer the page gets reloaded, the chosen answer gets saved in the database and the form with the same question and answers gets displayed again - but with the difference, that the correct answer is highlighted in green and the buttons are disabled (in order to prevent users from clicking another time).

All this happens with all questions.

What I now want is to do exactly the same but without having to reload the page that often. I'd like to mark (highlight in green) the correct answer as soon as the user has chosen an answer by having clicked on a button or as soon as 10 seconds have passed.

I think of using Ajax in order to manage this but I have to pass the variables to the php script and therefore it would be easy for users to just look at the source code and get the correct answer, wouldn't it be?

Is there another opportunity of doing so, which is also secure (so that cheating isn't that easy)?

Comment: You only need to send the `question id` and the selected `answer id` to verify wether an user chose the correct answer

Comment: Well, yes, then the user can't see the correct answer in the source code but he's still able to imitate my request and with this he gets the correct answer, because I have to pass back from php to js which answer is correct.

Comment: If you are worried about brute force attacks then you should implement some security. You could limit the requests by logging the IP address and allowing only answering a specific question once every 10minutes, you could use a token in the mainform to be sure the request is sent from your domain only, ...

Comment: Well, I'm not worried about brute force attacks... But the thing with the token sounds interesting - could you explain that a bit more precise, please?

Comment: To ensure a request is sent from your form you could do these steps 1) Generate a random hashed string and store this in a session variable 2) Place this token in a hidden field 3) Sent the token with other data via ajax to your server and verify if it matches the session one, if so process the request, otherwise ignore the request

Comment: Generating a hashed string and store it in a session var sounds unnecessary because the user could run his script after having logged in and therefore the session var will always be correct if he runs the script. Am I wrong? Well, you can see the value of a hidden input field in the source code, can't you? Same for ajax request - you can see it in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, @K.I and @DarkBee, I think I've got a solution - I'll realize it using AJAX. The script with which ajax is communicating increases a session var. If the session var doesn't fit to another session var which gets increased by reloading the question page, I'll disqualify the user. I think that should do, anyway, I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can reload certain parts of your form using AJAX, as for security, you can just send the users input to the server and do all your processing in php file, so there is no way to see which answer is correct in case if anyone would attemt to cheat.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I would also have to pass the question id to the script. And a user could prepare a script that does the same as my script -> so he sends the question id and answer1 for instance to my script using a post param and gets as a result whether this answer is true or not. Do you know what i mean and can you see my problem? Or should I explain it more?

Comment: If it is a test, can you have it disabled and only enable it at the time of the test? I will be honest I haven't come across such a problem yet so I would be very interested in seeing other views.

Comment: In fact, it's not a test but a real quiz which will be played in our school (class vs class). Everyone plays several rounds and after the first round the user has enough time to evaluate how I pass the data and to create a script that imitates that. During the time to answer the question, he could get the question id, run his script and then click the correct button. I feel forced to add any security machanism or to solve it differently...